# Workflow Updates Seem to be occurring in Singlet and not bulk - Winter '16

Tags: apex

This just started happening today from code that has been working for over a year...

I am getting to many SOQL queries after insert of a record, it seems that the record is inserted, validation fire, then triggers run for a single record at a time:

> 16:20:49.560 (5560488920)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|copyPersonEmail on
>   Opportunity trigger event BeforeInsert for [new, new, new, new, new,
>   new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new,
>   new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new,
>   new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new,
>   new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new,
>   new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new,
>   new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new,
>   new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new, new,
>   new, new] 16:20:49.591
>   (5591665195)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Opportunity:new
>   16:20:49.592
>   (5592206080)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Opportunity:new
>   16:20:49.592
>   (5592242761)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Opportunity:new
>   16:20:49.592
>   (5592725692)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Opportunity:new

..Repeating validations, notice the **new** for the id...

then

> 16:20:49.625
>   (5625171465)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Opportunity:new
>   16:20:49.625
>   (5625451918)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Opportunity:new
>   16:20:50.567
>   (6567681496)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qE0000000E0jH|copyPersonEmail
>   on Opportunity trigger event BeforeUpdate for [006E000000YBzwo]
>   16:20:50.567 (6567733406)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8

Notice that the before update is happening on a **SINGLE ID 006E000000YBzwo**

The trigger that is running is this:

```
trigger copyPersonEmail on Opportunity (Before Insert, Before Update) {

Set<ID> accIDs = New Set<ID>();

for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
    accIDs.add(o.AccountID);

Map<ID,Account> acc = New Map<ID,Account>([select PersonEmail From Account Where ID IN :AccIDs]);



for(Opportunity o : trigger.new){
    if(acc.containsKey(o.AccountID))
        o.PersonEmail__c = acc.get(o.Accountid).PersonEmail;
}

}
```

The debug logs are set to debug for Apex, system, and Finest for workflow rules.

This is in a bulk context. When done with a limit of 5 on the query it works as expected with the trigger running on all records.

Anyone have any insight as to why this could be happening

Note: Worked around it by creating a formula field on the Opp then copying that field. But it still does not answer why the before update was only operating on a single record....

Weird part is, if I LIMITED the query to 5 records, the trigger operated on the 5 records and not the single record....Additional attempts and varying debug log level never showed anything happening between the validation and the beforeUpdate executing.....